# VBA ADO query on Excel workbook

Tags: vba

I have the following code to retrieve data from another workbook. However I want the SQL code take into account a where clause. This where clause should be applied on one of the columns. Up till now my code works but not after adding the where clause. The column header is Cost_center. What should I write differently in my code to let the code only get data where the Cost_center column is like a certain number?

```
Sub newbie2() Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\INP_DEPARTMENT_SOL_DEL.xlsx" & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
cn.Open strCon

strSQL = "SELECT * from [sheet1$] WHERE [COST_CENTER] LIKE 5560"
rs.Open strSQL, cn, 0, 1  'cursortype = adOpenForwardOnly, locktype = adOpenReadonly

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A").CopyFromRecordset rs
rs.Close
cn.Close

Set rs = Nothing
Set con = Nothing


End Sub
```

Thanks in advance,

Michiel

Comment: What are the incorrect results you are getting and what are the expected results?  This code works fine for me.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the issue.  Writing answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are not getting cost centers that contain "5560" but would get cost centers that are exactly "5560."

The problem is in this line:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * from [sheet1$] WHERE [COST_CENTER] LIKE 5560"
```

The `LIKE` statement requires wildcard characters.  For ADO, the wildcard character is `%`

Change the code to:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * from [sheet1$] WHERE [COST_CENTER] LIKE '%5560%'"
```

and it should work as desired.